# Updating JSON file with PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to modify my JSON file with a PHP solution :
From this file :

```
[   
  {      
    "id":40764465700014,
    "Pays":"France",
    "lat":43.221401,
    "long":6.1424990000000435
  }
]
```

To this file :

```
[
{"id" : "40764465700014",
"Pays" : { "add" : "France" },
"lat" : { "add" : 43.221401 },
"long" : { "add" : 6.1424990000000435}
}
]
```

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Load the file, use `json_decode()`, change the contents use `json_encode()` and save the file again. Where is the problem?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Can you give us more context? It seems you are trying something with a certain goal in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use  `json_decode()` and convert it to array , then just encode the array into json using `json_encode()`. Use the code below

```
<?php
$json = '[   
  {      
    "id":40764465700014,
    "Pays":"France",
    "lat":43.221401,
    "long":6.1424990000000435
  }
]';
$array= json_decode($json,true);
echo json_encode($array[0]);
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you very much !
But how can I access the string in "Pays" for example ?